# Preciso que para o formulário passar para a próxima página todos os campos estejam preenchidos, caso não estejam, o botão será bloqueado

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const prevBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-prev");
const nextBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-next");
const progress = document.getElementById("progress");
const formSteps = document.querySelectorAll(".form-step");
const progressSteps = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-step");

let formStepsNum = 0;


nextBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    formStepsNum++;
    updateFormSteps();
    updateProgressbar();
  });
});

prevBtns.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    formStepsNum--;
    updateFormSteps();
    updateProgressbar();
  });
});

function updateFormSteps() {
  formSteps.forEach((formStep) => {
    formStep.classList.contains("form-step-active") &&
      formStep.classList.remove("form-step-active");
  });

  formSteps[formStepsNum].classList.add("form-step-active");
}

function updateProgressbar() {
  progressSteps.forEach((progressStep, idx) => {
    if (idx < formStepsNum + 1) {
      progressStep.classList.add("progress-step-active");
    } else {
      progressStep.classList.remove("progress-step-active");
    }
  });

  const progressActive = document.querySelectorAll(".progress-step-active");

  progress.style.width =
    ((progressActive.length - 1) / (progressSteps.length - 1)) * 100 + "%";
}
```

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #6425A5;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat, "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
/* Global Stylings */
label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

select{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.width-50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Progressbar */
.progressbar {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  counter-reset: step;
  margin: 2rem 0 4rem;
}

.progressbar::before,
.progress {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  z-index: -1;
}

.progress {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  width: 0%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.progress-step {
  width: 2.1875rem;
  height: 2.1875rem;
  background-color: #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.progress-step::before {
  counter-increment: step;
  content: counter(step);
}

.progress-step::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 0.5rem);
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: #666;
}

.progress-step-active {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #f3f3f3;
}

/* Form */


.form-step {
  display: none;
  transform-origin: top;
  animation: animate 0.5s;
}

.form-step-active {
  display: block;
}

.input-group {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}


/* Button */
.btns-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  color: #f3f3f3;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff, 0 0 0 3px var(--primary-color);
}

.info{
 margin-top: 20%;
 padding-left: 20%;
}

.info-2{
margin-top: 7%;
padding-left: 28%;
}

.info-3{
margin-top: -1%;
padding-left: 89px;
padding-right: 70px;
}

.form-link{
text-align: center;
}

.form-link span,
.form-link a{
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;

}

.form a{
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Cadastro.css">


  <!----===== Boxicons CSS ===== -->
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>

  <!-- Fonte-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Da+2&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="sidebar close">

    <!-- Começo dos Passos do Formulario de Cadastro -->
    <div class="form-wrapper2" id="wrapper-signup">
      <div class="content-wrapper" id="content-signin">
        <form action="../../Banco/cadastro.php" class="form" method="POST">
          <h1 class="text-center">Cadastro</h1>

          <!-- Barrinha de Progresso -->
          <div class="progressbar">
            <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>

            <div class="progress-step progress-step-active" data-title=""></div>
            <div class="progress-step" data-title=""></div>
            <div class="progress-step" data-title=""></div>
          </div>

          <!-- Passos -->

          <!-- Formulario 1 User Data e Sexo -->
          <div class="form-step form-step-active" id="form-1">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label for="username">Nome completo</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="username" placeholder="Digite seu nome completo" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label for="position">Data de Nascimento</label>
              <input type="date" name="data" id="dt_nascimento" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" >
              <label for="dob" >Sexo</label>
              <select name="sexo" required>
                <option disabled selected >Qual o seu sexo ?</option>
                <option>1 - Masculino</option>
                <option>2 - Feminino</option>
                <option>3 - Outros</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="">
              <a class="btn btn-next width-50 ml-auto" id="btn_danton2">Avançar</a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="link">
              <p>Já possui uma conta ?<a href="#wrapper-login"> Login</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Formulario 2 Email e Senha -->
          <div class="form-step" id="form-2">
            <div class="input-group">
              <label for="email">E-mail</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="name" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label for="Senha">Senha</label>
              <input type="text" name="senha" id="instituicao" placeholder="Digite sua senha" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
              <label for="Senha">Confirmar Senha</label>
              <input type="text" name="" id="instituicao" placeholder="Digite sua senha novamente" />
            </div>
            <div class="btns-group">
              <a class="btn btn-prev">Voltar</a>
              <input type="submit" value="Confirmar" class="btn btn-next">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="link">
              <p>Já possui uma conta ?<a href="#wrapper-login"> Login</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Formulario 3 Confirmação do Cadastro -->
          <div class="form-step" id="form-3">
            <div class="mensagem">
              <div class="info">
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i><span> Sua conta
                  foi criada com sucesso!</span>
              </div>
              <div class="info-2">
                <p>Obrigado(a) pelo seu tempo.
              </div><br>
              <div class="info-3">
                Só mais uma coisa. Nós iremos reiniciar sua página para você efetuar o seu
                login.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="Cadastro.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia colocar a tag required para os inputs  do formulário fazendo com que ele se torne obrigatório. Dessa forma assim não teria como ele passar para a próxima pagina sem preencher todos os campo.

exemplo:`<input type="text" required>`

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).